# Declare "pending" specs/tests in jasmine or mocha

Tags: jasmine, mocha.js

I would like to describe specifications that should be in the code, but implementation of them would be added later. In test results I would like to see them neither passed nor failed, but "are waiting" for implementation instead.

I'm interested if it is possible to do out of the box in mocha or jasmine.

Thanks

Comment: Please change which answer you accepted here, as the originally-accepted answer is no longer correct as of `Jasmine 2.0`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can declare disabled functions in both mocha and jasmine using `xit` (instead of `it`), and `xdescribe` (instead of describe).

If you want the tests to appear as pending, in mocha you can just leave the second parameter blank in the call to the `it()` function. For example:

```
describe('Something', function () {
    it('Should be pending')
    xit('Should be disabled, i.e not appear on the list')
});
```

Update: The behaviour for `xit`/`xdescribe` is might change in Mocha if this merge happens: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/510

Comment: Thank you. So now xit don't show it in report, and after the merge it will, if I got it right? Actually I would like to see them in the report.

Comment: If you want them to show in the report currently, I suggest using it() without the second parameter (the test function). The test runner will then mark it as pending.

Comment: how does the test runner mark them as pending? AFAIK, jasmine shows them as a 'pass'?

Comment: [in Jasmine 1.5] `it()` with no second parameter shows up as a pass, which I would not consider pending. `xit()` and `xdescribe()` (latter needs a function second param) aren't pending; they're completely ignored and not mentioned in the UI. `this.fail('message');` will manually fail a test; also not pending. Jasmine v2 will apparently have a true "pending" state.

Answer (score 24):

Starting with Jasmine 2.0, writing `xit()` instead of `it()` for a spec marks it as pending (as already said in a comment of the accepted answer).

Aditionally, there is a `pending()` function you can call anywhere inside a spec to mark it as pending:

```
it("can be declared by calling 'pending' in the spec body", function() {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
  pending();
});
```

See also the [documentation on pending specs in Jasmine 2.0](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs).

Comment: `pending("This is the reason why it is pending");`

Answer (score 15):

In mocha, you can also use `skip`:

```
describe('my module', function() {
  it.skip('works', function() {
    // nothing yet
  });
});
```

You can also do `describe.skip` to skip whole sections.

Comment: `describe.skip()` and `it.skip()` is much cleaner than `xdescribe` and `xit`